# How to get an array from Content script to background.js and other js file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a fetch request from Contentscript and storing that resolved promise data in an array. However i would like to access that array in another Js file i have called index.js Below is my code

```
let pluginData = [];

let request = 'www.dummydata.com';
(async () =>{
        const rawResponse = await fetch(request);
        const data = await rawResponse.json();
        let result = pluginData.push(data);
      })();

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(pluginData,function(response){ });
```

Here is my index.js file

```
 let profiles = [];

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        getUserResults(request, sender, sendResponse);
    });

    async function getUserResults(request, sender, sendResponse){
         profiles = await request;
        console.log(profiles);

        for (let i =0; i < profiles.length;i++){

            function setHtml(id, value) {
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
            }

        setHtml('pending_requests', `${profiles[0].pending_requests}`);

        return true;
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: 1) An async anonymous function returns a Promise so you'll have to await it in the outer scope too, otherwise sendMessage will run before you collect the data, 2) it's not clear what **exactly** is happening now - you need to use devtools debugger to set breakpoints and debug the code, 3) it's not clear where index.js is running - if it's declared as a background script in manifest.json then it's a separate hidden page, see [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/10258029)

Comment: background.js is a separate file. i just need to access the array from content.js to index.js and use those array values.

Comment: You didn't clarify where index.js is running. If it's a browserAction popup, it's a separate window as well, with its own devtools which you can invoke by right-clicking the popup, then click "inspect". Also note, the popup doesn't run when it's not shown so you can't send messages to a closed popup.

Comment: index.js is a page action popup. I have updated my index.js code , so you can get an idea of what iam trying to achieve

Comment: 1. page action is also a separate window with its own devtools, and it exists only when shown, 2. `request` is not a function so no need to await it, 3. anyway, debug it in devtools as this is a primary dev tool, duh, in the browser, that is.